# Angular 2 data binding to a non-input

Tags: typescript, angular

Angular 2 Version:`rc.1`

I am returning a list of names and places in a table using *ngFor and **I want to bind the data to the cell that I click on to a variable in my component**.

component.html

```
<tr *ngFor="let result of Results$">
  <td #foo (click)="passValue(foo)">
    {{result?.name}}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{result?.place}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

component.ts

```
passValue(foo) {
  this.value = foo;
  console.log(foo);
}
```

In the console I am getting the following when I click on a cell with "John" as its value:

```
<td _ngcontent-pof-13="">
    John
</td>
```

Ideally, the console would just log "John" instead of the entire td element.

Or maybe there is an entirely different and better way to do it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tr *ngFor="let result of Results$">
   <td #foo (click)="passValue(foo)">
```

`#foo` here is a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ref-vars) - a reference to the DOM element itself. `result` is a reference to the data you're binding to - in this case, an object with name field with value "John":

So, replace

```
<td #foo (click)="passValue(foo)">  // prints the td element
```

by:

```
<td #foo (click)="passValue(result?.name)"> // prints "John"
```

Comment: `result` is the entire object; wouldn't you want to pass `result.name` if you wanted the console to print "John" in `passValue`?

Comment: Yes, Metro Smurf that is what I ended up doing and it worked

Comment: @MetroSmurf good eye, thanks for pointing that out. answer updated.

Comment: It actually did not need the ? operator here, but for some reason I need it for displaying the values

Comment: @EricScandora - that's called the Elvis operator, you should google it. It prevents the error that would otherwise occur if `result` was undefined when the template is drawn

Comment: @drewmoore I will definitely look into it. Up in your answer the passValue(result?.name) does not need the elvis operator, I have it working in my project with your answer and no elvis operator.

Comment: I put it there to be consistent with what's in your question. It "does not need" it when result is defined, but set `result = undefined` and you'll see what it's doing for you

Comment: Okay, great! Good to know